# My java method is returning 0.0 when it is supposed to output a random number, why isn't it working?

Tags: java

This is for an intro to programming course. I'm supposed to make a program that will draw a variety of objects on a turtle graphics displayer at a number of random places, however in order to ensure that the random places are on the board, I am supposed to use the method `public int generateCoordinate(int limit)`

The limit value is supposed to be 35, and it is supposed to be a modifier to the randomly generated number to ensure that nothing is off-screen.

When I attempt to apply this, however, my code returns nothing but 0.0.

Here's my full code with the limit set to 5:

```
public class debug
{
    private int x;
    private int coord;
    

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class debug
     */
    public debug()
    {
        generateCoordinate(5);
        System.out.println(coord);
    }
    public int generateCoordinate(int limit){
        double coord = (Math.random()*301-159);
        if (coord<(-150+limit))
        return (int)coord + limit;
        if (coord>(150-limit))
        return (int)coord - limit;

        return (int)coord;
    }
    }
```

When I have the program print the result, it comes out as 0.0, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: have you debugged your code? How exactly do you have a method with return type int, to return 0.0??

Comment: I ran your code, with parameter 5, it returned 52. Your method can not possibly return 0.0, only an int (so, 0, probably).

Comment: My mistake, it was returning 0.0 after I had converted the result to a double. Regardless, it's still only returning 0. As I said this is an intro to computer science class so I'm extremely new to this, I have no idea how to debug code.

Comment: as I said, I executed your code. It doesn't return 0.0, not in the form it is now, and not when you return a double.

Comment: Please write a complete program we can run, and edit your question to include it. Make sure you run it and check that the problem is still there.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the complete program, when I run it the output remains at zero.

Comment: Your test code ignores the return value of the `generateCoordinate()` method and instead of that return value prints the value of the field `coord` that is initialized to 0 and never changes.

Comment: That certainly explains my problem, how would I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be variable scope of `coord`

You have 1 `coord` at Class level, and 1 overshadowing `coord` variable inside your method.

The return value of `generateCoordinate` is linked to the method scoped variable.
While the `debug` method will read the value from the Class scope, which is never written.

```java
public class debug
{
    private int x;
    private int coord;
    
    public debug()
    {
        generateCoordinate(5);
        System.out.println(coord); // class scope
        
        // Try it like this instead
        coord = generateCoordinate(5); // write the class scope with the method return value
        System.out.println(coord); // class scope
    }

    public int generateCoordinate(int limit){
        double coord = (Math.random()*301-159); // Method scope
        if (coord<(-150+limit))
            return (int)coord + limit;
        if (coord>(150-limit))
            return (int)coord - limit;

        return (int)coord; // still method scope
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are printing *coord*, you'll need to assign it a value.
The default *int* value, when unassigned, is *0*.

```java
public debug()
{
    coord = generateCoordinate(5);
    System.out.println(coord);
}
```

Furthermore, the *[Math#random](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#random())* method is going to return a *double* value between 0 and 1.

You can use the following algorithm to get a range.
Where, *35* is your *limit*, and *1* is your *lower bound*.

```
(Math.random() * 35 - 1) + 1
```

I recommend using the *[Random](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html)* class.
It's the same object that *[Math#random](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#L892)* is utilizing *[here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#L854)*.

The *[Random#nextDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html#nextDouble(double,double))* method allows you to set an *origin*, and *upper bound*.
Note, the *upper bound* is exclusive, so you'll need to use *36*, if your *limit* is *35*.

```java
public int generateCoordinate(int limit){
    Random random = new Random();
    double coord = random.nextDouble(1, limit + 1);
    if (coord<(-150+limit))
        return (int)coord + limit;
    if (coord>(150-limit))
        return (int)coord - limit;

    return (int)coord;
}
```

Output

```
21
9
15
3
15
```

Comment: seeing as you can't reproduce the problem, how can you give an answer to "solve" the problem?

Comment: This doesn't help me, like I said, for the assignment i need to specifically use the code public int generateCoordinate(int limit), I can't substitute it for something else.

Comment: @Mars, you can't change any code within it, just the numbers, _301-159_?

Comment: Sorry I totally misconstrued what you were saying, I'm very frazzled right now. I applied your code, and the output remains 0

Comment: @Mars, you'll need to assign _generateCoordinate(5)_ to _coord_.  _coord = generateCoordinate(5)_.

Comment: Solved, thank you so much Reilas